# (string<? "alpha" "bet") ⇒ true. How is this statement true?

Tags: scheme, racket

`(string<? "alpha" "bet")⇒ true`

How is this statement true?

What does the string< calculate? bet has less characters than alpha.

Comment: What you want is expressed as `(< (string-length "alpha") (string-length "bet"))`.

Comment: `#\a` comes earlier in th alphabet than `#\b`.

Answer (score 6):

The [`string<?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string~3c~3f%29%29) procedure is using [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) for performing the comparison. In other words: if the string `"alpha"` appears before `"bet"` in a dictionary, then it's *less than* it - the string's length is not taken into account. Quoting the documentation:

> Returns `#t` if the arguments are lexicographically sorted increasing, where individual characters are ordered by `char<?`, `#f` otherwise.